# How to make Onclick code to not execute when a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, href

Not sure how to get this code to not fire if a hyperlink was clicked

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();

  $('.accordion-list > li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          
      ////if link is clicked then exit this function////
       
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
      
    } else {
        
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the event target to get the clicked element (which could be a descendent of the `<li>`). If the target has any ancestors that are `<a>`s, stop the function.

```
$('.accordion-list > li').click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        if (event.target.closest('a')) {
            // an <a> was clicked
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to prevent click continue execute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();

  // ***** pass event parameter e
  $('.accordion-list > li').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          
      // ***** prevent click to continue execute 
      e.preventDefault();
      
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
      
    } else {
        
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });
```